# Webpage design is not coming properly

Tags: javascript, css, html

After I put another section id for MAPCHART, BARCHART doesn't work.
Before that it work properly.

Below the image non-working part [after I put MAPCHART] and working part[before I put MAPCHART].

For BARCHART CSS:
main.css only

[Site is here](http://ranjan720.github.io/)

[Code is here](https://github.com/ranjan720/ranjan720.github.io)

[image: Error]

Comment: not sure if that's ur problem but there seems some errors in js links they are wrong as you have css/colorbrewer.js which should be js/colorbrewer.js and script.js under js folder as well

Comment: Thank for the error head up. And I found the mistake, as I used same variable in both dataset for two different charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct CSS Inline style in this id="mapcharts (background-color:white)